# how to wrap text in excel using java

Tags: java, apache-poi

i need to wrap text in a description column using java
i'm using style.setWrapText(); its not working

```
public CellStyle getDefaultCellStyle(Workbook workbook, boolean isAlignCenter) {
    CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
    style.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.THIN);
    style.setWrapText(true);

    if (isAlignCenter)
        style.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);

    return style;
}
```

Comment: For me (and thousands of other `apache poi` users) `CellStyle.setWrapText` works properly. So your issue is not reproducible from your provided code snippet. Please show a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).